# Selenium/Watir: 'InvalidCookieDomain' error when trying to add cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, watir

I am new into **[WATIR](https://github.com/watir/watir)**, or Selenium, but I was trying to add a cookie into my WATIR browser, as below:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox    
browser.goto(url)
browser.cookies.add name,value, domain: ".www.example.com"
```

I am prompted with the following error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: ReferenceError: **InvalidCookieDomainError** is not defined

But, when I delete the domain option, it works.

I was wondering why I can't add a different domain into my cookies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like **WATIR**, all Selenium-based frameworks create language-specific wrappers to Selenium pre-defined commands. These commands are defined **[here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver)** in the Selenium Webdriver W3C standard.

If you go to **[Cookies](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#add-cookie)** section, specifically, the `addCookie` sub-section, you will see the following:

> If the current browsing context’s document element is a **[cookie-averse Document object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#cookie-averse-document-object)**, return error with **error code invalid cookie domain**.

Your `domain` attribute is bound to the same domain as your given `url`. So, basically, your domain **HAS** to be the same as your current `url`, or a sub-domain of the `url`.

**Example:** For `url=global.nba.com`, you can set cookies for both the sub-domain (`{domain: "global.nba.com"}`), as well as for the root-domain (`{domain: "nba.com"}`).

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox    
browser.goto(url)
browser.cookies.add("<yourCookieName>","<yourCookieValue>", {domain: "<sameUrlOriginDomain>"})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer but what if i want add dot `"."` before `"global.nba.com"` so it will be `".globla.nba.con"` because i want add dot before origin url ?

Comment: @taylor from my knowledge, yes as long as it doesn't interfere with the same origin rule I just told you about. So your `url` on which you are adding the cookie, must be the parent or direct sibling of the domain you are using. Can you give the example so we can validate? Also accept the answer if it answered your question. Thanks.

Comment: @taylor I've just tested the functionality and it allows preceding the domain value with a dot (`.`).

Comment: Thanks mate, it helps

Comment: What is the point of setting the cookie _after_ the `goto()` call? We want to set it _before_, don't we?

Comment: You cannot set cookies unless you first open the specific URL. For the `cookies` command to work,  it implies you have already loaded the URL & the `domain` value matches the parent domain of your URL. If you don't want retroactive configs via cookies, then try the use of custom headers. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had to go to the url first before setting a cookie, e.g.

```rb
      visit root_path
      ('f'..'k').each.with_index do |cookie, index|
        Helper::Browser.set_cookie(:esid, cookie)
        visit root_path
      end
```